# iceberg with lzma compression

Tags: macos, package, packagemaker, lzma

I use iceberg to distribute my packages for OS X platform.

I want to compress my files with lzma algorithm like in nsis (for windows).

I researched this but I couldn't find anything about it. Probably there is no solution for iceberg and lzma but I have an hope.

Somebody know how to use iceberg with lzma compression?

Answer (score 0):

NSIS for windows is great but you need to use it with [Excelsior Installer 2.2](http://www.excelsior-usa.com). I know another software to build package with LZMA compression : [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com). You can try for some better results.

Comment: I was looking it for OS X platform. I am so happy with nsis in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The only lzma installer solutions i know about were kinda custom builds. A default osx installer with embedded 7za binary for extraction and a seperate lzma archive that is extracted using a postflight script. I wouldnt expect an lzma integration into osx, therefore the installers wont support lzma. All you can do is embedding the binary and control extraction using package scripts. One thing is shure, once you experienced the excellent solid compression ratios of lzma on executables you'll never use anything else ;) results are even better than using nsis on win.

Create the metapackage, add install options, build. Add the lzma binary and archive(s) to the (meta)package folder(s) and handle the extraction inside the package(s) postflight script(s). You can adjust the real install sizes in kb editing the integer value of IFPkgFlagInstalledSize Info.plist inside the pkg folder.

A side note: if youre after compressing audio samples, lzma isnt the preferred choice. Gzip and RAR a way more comfortable for this purpose, and way faster.

Comment: Hi, My new product needs time to release, I will try your suggestion at that time. Thank you.